# Running Sudowin on Windows 11

Tags: sudo, windows-11

It's the first time I need to run Sudowin on Windows 11 and the service won't start. I've tested a sudoers.xml file that runs on Windows 10 with the same language and it doesn't work.
It renders the following event on event viewer:
'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: There was an exception in the invocation target. ---> System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some of the identities refered weren't converted. (loosely translated from non english error)

Is there anyone out there that was able to rescue this powerfull tool on windows 11?

The alternatives runas, elevate and sudo for windows (powershell-gsudo) aren't an option. I need that a non-administrator user can run a specific program with administrator privileges without loosing his profile (home folder, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Sudowin is from 2008 - 14 years ago. It's not surprising that it doesn't
work in Windows 11.

Some solutions you could try are (without recommendation) :

- [AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html) (freeware)
- [Make Me Admin](https://github.com/pseymour/MakeMeAdmin/wiki/) (freeware)
- [RunAsTool](https://www.sordum.org/8727/runastool-v1-4/) (freeware)
- [RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html) (commercial)
- [Runasrob](https://runasrob.com/) (commercial)
  The free version has an annoying popup window which appears randomly.

Comment: Advanced run and Make Me Admin - Don't have nothing like a sudoers file. This won't let me select what programs can be run with higher previleges.
RunAsTool and RunAsSpc - Will use the profile of the impersonated user.
Nevertheless RunAsTool will be my workaround as currently there isn't a sudo like program for Windows 11.

Comment: These tools generally are very insecure: https://micksmix.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/capturing-credentials-from-encrypted-runas-software/

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here:
https://sourceforge.net/p/sudowin/bugs/39/

The problem is that the the config files refer to the groups "Administrators" and "Users". You have to translate this to the localized version on your OS in these files at Program Files (x86)\Sudowin\Server:

- sudoers.xml
- Sudowin.Server.exe.config